# F# initialize objects inside struct with constructor

Tags: class, struct, constructor, f#, initialization

I have the following struct in F#:

```
type public Data = 
    struct
        val class1: Class1
        new() {
            class1 = new Class1()
        }
    end
```

But I get an error that says structs cannot have an empty constructor. Class1 is a class that has a valid default constructor, and needs to be initialized before it is used. Thus, I want class1 to call its constructor when the Data struct is created. How can I do this, or should I not be doing this at all?

Comment: In .NET a value type (struct) can't have a constructor with no parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter mentioned in the comments, structs cannot have constructors with no arguments. In fact, if you fix the syntax (add the `=` sign), the F# compiler tells you exactly this:

```
type public Data = 
  struct
    val class1: Class1
    new() = { class1 = new Class1() }
  end
```

> error FS0870: Structs cannot have an object constructor with no arguments. This is a restriction imposed on all CLI languages as structs automatically support a default constructor.

Your best chance is probably to create a struct with (possibly private) constructor taking the `Class1` value, and add a static method that lets you create the default instance using `Data.Create()`:

```
[<Struct>]
type Data private(class1:Class1) =
  static member Create() = Data(new Class1())
```

You could write this using `struct .. end` too, but I personally prefer using the simpler object notation and just add the `Struct` attribute.